SystemVerilog threads execution order
I am trying to start few threads in SystemVerilog, as can be seen in the code below:
    module tb;
      int done = 0;
      initial
        begin
          for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            begin
              automatic int val = i;
              fork
                begin
                  $display("+ThreadA %0d", val);
                  done[val] = 1;
                end
              join_none
            end
    
          for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            begin
              @(done[i] == 1);
            end
          $display("All threads done");
        end
    endmodule

The output from that code:
# +ThreadA 2
# +ThreadA 1
# +ThreadA 0

Why is "ThreadA 2" displayed first, while the loop should have started "ThreadA 0" before that? My expected output was

# +ThreadA 0
# +ThreadA 1
# +ThreadA 2


The code in EDAPlayground with Questa.

join would stop the execution of the parent thread till all the child threads are done, right?
Threads are needed in my case as the actual code is more complex and this was just a simpler example of code to present my question.

The fork/join_none construct schedules a thread to start in the current event region when the parent thread suspends or terminates. The way your loop executes, three child threads get scheduled before parent thread suspends. Because of section 4.7 Nondeterminism in the IEEE 1800-2023 SystemVerilog LRM, those threads can start in any order. However, for debug ability, a particular version of a tool will never change the order you see.
But even if you see a particular starting order for each thread, it's technically possible for the first $display statement in the thread to execute in one order, and the second assignment statement to execute in a different order. That same section of the LRM says events can be executed in any order between threads. The only guarantee is the two statements inside the begin/block execute in order within each thread. This becomes an issue if you try to execute your simulation on a multicore platform.
Note that you want to use a level sensitive wait (done[i] == 1); not the edge sensitive @. If you loop in the opposite order that done gets set your loop hangs.

Threads are by their essence asynchronous — you may not predict when an individual thread begins, ends, or executes a particular command.
In other words, the order of your output lines is nondeterministic.

I am not sure I understand the idea here, but "join_none" is used right after the end of the fork block, if I change the order that would mean it comes after the for loop which creates a compile error.

In your code the join_none command is used 3 times, because you placed it into the for loop. The same for your fork command.

Yes so the intention is that each iteration would spawn a thread, and that the main thread does not wait for the thread to end right after creating hence I used join_none, and at the end done is used to indicate that each thread was completed.

OK, so I shortened my answer only to express the basic about multitasking / multithreading.

When I try to run the code you posted in your EDA Playground link, I get errors.
But, when I copy your code into EDAPlayground and run it on a different simulator (Synopsys), I get a different result (the result you expected):
+ThreadA 0
+ThreadA 1
+ThreadA 2

This demonstrates that the result is indeterminate.  According to the IEEE Std 1800-2023, a simulator may implement the order in any way it sees fit.  This is why we see different results with different simulators.  You may even see different results with different versions of the same simulator.
In other words, when you write code like this, you can not rely on a specific order of execution of the $display statements.
